# Pandas Series to Numpy ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-3.6

I have a dataframe similar to this (but much larger).

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([ [ 'a', np.array([ 1, 2]) ], [ 'b', np.array([ 3, 4 ]) ] ])
   0       1
0  a  [1, 2]
1  b  [3, 4]
```

The last column has the shape listed as...

```
>>> df[1].shape
(2,)
```

I'd like it to be listed as `(2,2)`. I was able to do this via the following line, but the performance of `tolist()` is... bad.

```
>>> np.array(df[1].tolist()).shape
(2, 2)
```

It could also be a Pandas dataframe as long as it correctly reports the shape. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by having changing the shape to `(2,2)`?  Will `df[1]` always be an array of 2 numbers?

Comment: @vealkind yes, it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible!

Pandas keeps each `Series` as a single dimensional `ndarray`.  If you have multiple dimensions that you are trying to squeeze into it, Pandas will force this to be a single dimensional array with `dtype` of `object`.

If you simply want to get the contents and make it into a 2 dimensional array then I'd suggest

```
np.array(df[1].values.tolist())
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest you keep them in two different columns.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a Pandas series. It could be a numpy array. I'm wondering if there's better way than converting it to a list first.

Comment: The difference between what I've done and what you did was that I accessed the `values` attribute and used Numpy's `tolist` rather than going through Pandas' `tolist`.  But it's the best option you have.  If you are worried about performance, then you should reconsider putting 2-element array like things in a single column in the first place.

Comment: It's actually `(50, 25)`. So not quite the same as just a 2-element array. That was a toy problem.

Comment: Same thing.  Keep in a larger dataframe with appropriate number of columns.

Comment: I do need to work with it in a `(50, 25)` format. Do you think reshaping is faster than the conversion?

Comment: Yes!  IIUC, yes.  Keep a dataframe with 25 columns that is created from the `(50, 25)` array and you can access that array with `df.values` and reshape it as needed.

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant that `(50, 25)` is the size of the nested array. I'm working with ~1k data frames which each have 5k rows. Each of those rows has the `(50, 25)`. So it would end up being `1,250+` columns.

Comment: I think this deserves more clarity and maybe a question of its own

Comment: Would you pose that question as an optimization? I.e. what's better?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  I wouldn't say it's strictly necessary, but it makes sense.